# Lipschitz constant <1

Tags: real-analysis

I have an old exam problem asking the following: If  $f : [0, 1] → [0, 1]$ is Lipschitz continuous with a Lipschitz constant $L<1$, show there is exactly one $x ∈ [0, 1]$ for which  $f(x) = x$ is true.

I can see why there can only be one such $x$, because else $\frac{f(x)-f(y)}{x-y} = \frac{x-y}{x-y} = 1$, hence damaging the condition $L<1$. However, I can't prove why there must be exactly one such $x$.

Comment: Consider $g(x)=f(x)-x.$ Is it $g(0)\ge 0?$ Is it $g(1)\le 0?$

Comment: Well yes, but I don't see your point.

Comment: So, there exists $c\in [0,1]$ such that $g(c)=c.$ In other words: $f(c)=c.$ Thus $f$ has at least a fixed point. And you have shown that it doesn't have more than one.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach_fixed-point_theorem

Comment: Thanks that settles it I guess. Looks like the prof gave a problem from a part in the script we never reached lol.